# Proof that $\Phi(G) \le N$ implies $\Phi(G) \le \Phi(N)$ for normal subgroup $N \unlhd G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be some finite group and $p$ some prime divisor of the order of $G$. Suppose $O_p(G) = 1$, i.e. the largest normal subgroup with order $p$ is trivial, and $G / N$ is a $p$-group for some normal subgroup $N$. Then $\Phi(N) = \Phi(G)$, i.e. the Frattini subgroups of $N$ and $G$ are equal.

This is an exercise from [The Theory of Finite Groups](https://books.google.de/books?id=iebSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR4&ots=fBc3RBfJb1&dq=kurzweil%20stellmacher&hl=de&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=kurzweil%20stellmacher&f=false) by Kurzweil and Stellmacher.

By an application of the Frattini argument we find that every Sylow subgroup of $\Phi(G)$ is normal in $G$, hence as $O_p(G) = 1$ we know that $p$ does not divide the order of $\Phi(G)$. Also as $G/N$ is a $p$-group we can deduce $\Phi(G) \le N$. Now maybe it is true that if the Frattini subgroup of the whole group is contained in some normal subgroup $N$, then $\Phi(G) \le \Phi(N)$ might hold. I tried to show that $\Phi(G) \le M$ for every maximal subgroup $M$ of $N$, for if not we have some $x \in \Phi(G)$ such that $\langle x, M \rangle = N$. But that is all I can deduce, I do not see how to get a contradiction from that...

The other inclusion is a previous exercise, which I solved. For if $N \unlhd G$, then $\Phi(N) \unlhd G$. Let $M \le G$ be some maximal subgroup, if $\Phi(N)$ is not contained in $M$ then $M\Phi(N) = G$, hence $N = N \cap M\Phi(N) = (N\cap M)\Phi(N)$ by Dedekinds modular law, which implies $N = N\cap M$, or $N \le M$, which gives $\Phi(N) \le M$ contrary to our assumption. Hence $\Phi(N) \le M$ for every maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

So any suggestions how to show the implication $\Phi(G) \le \Phi(N)$?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 Oh sorry, I meant the Frattini subgroups by $\Phi(G)$! The intersection of the maximal subgroups.

Comment: I think one can proceed inductively to a certain extent. However, is there a simple proof in the case that $\Phi(N)=1$ and/or $N$ is a Sylow group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\Phi(N) \le \Phi(G)$, we have $\Phi(N/\Phi(N))=1$ and $\Phi(G/\Phi(N)) = \Phi(G)/\Phi(N)$.

Assume for a contradiction that $\Phi(G) \ne \Phi(N)$, and so $\Phi(G/\Phi(N)) \ne 1$. Let $M/\Phi(N)$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $\Phi(G)/\Phi(N)$. Then $M/\Phi(N)$ is an elementary abelian $q$-subgroup of $G$ for some prime $q$ and, since we know that $p$ does not divide $|\Phi(G)|$, we have $q \ne p$. Since $\Phi(G) \le N$, we have $M \le N$.

Since $\Phi(N/\Phi(N)) = 1$, $M/\Phi(N)$ has a complement in $N/\Phi(N)$ by Exercise 2 on page 76 of the book. Now by Gaschütz's Theorem (3.3.2 in the book), since $|M/\Phi(N)|$ and $|G:N|$ are coprime, $M/\Phi(N)$ has a complement in $G/\Phi(N)$. But that contradicts $M/\Phi(N) \le \Phi(G/\Phi(N))$.

Comment: Well done Derek- I'm glad I was thinking along similar lines. There were a number of loose ends in what I was thinking though. How did you dismiss the possibility $O_p(G/\Phi(N))\ne 1$.

Comment: Well it helps to have the book at hand, because solutions to exercises have to use previously proved results. Do you mean how do I rule out $O_p(G/\Phi(N)) \ne 1$? I don't think I need that condition, I only need $M$ not to be a $p$-group.

Comment: Right - thanks.

Comment: How you conclude that $M$ is not a $p$-group? I mean for example $G = C_{p^2} \times C_p$ with $N \cong C_p \times C_p$ fulfill $\Phi(N) = 1$ and all assumptions except $O_p(G) = 1$, but surely a minimal normal subgroup of $N$ must be a $p$-group...

Comment: Perhaps it was a bad idea to assume that $\Phi(N) = 1$. In terms of the original group $G$, $M/\Phi(N)$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $\Phi(G/\Phi(N)) = \Phi(G)/N$. But, as you remarked yourself, $p$ does not divide $|\Phi(G)|$ so $M$ cannot be a $p$-group.

Comment: I have now rewritten the solution without assuming WLOG that $\Phi(N)=1$, which was probably a bad idea. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thank you. I see, somehow thought you meant the assumption $O_p(G) = 1$ is not necessary, but now I see what you meant, that we could have $O_p(G / \Phi(N)) \ne 1$, but still assuming $O_p(G) = 1$.